# loop through list of URLs using HttpWebRequest causing error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, httpwebrequest

Looping through a list of urls in my MVC view

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(@item.URL) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    using (HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            //Move to the next record
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the the Do something fine but when an error occurs it can not move to the next record.

I Get a Server error The remote name could not be resolved: Followed by the url in the loop.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always read the documentation: the `GetResponse` method of the `HttpWebRequest` class can throw a  `WebException`, which is what you are getting. Basically, your code never gets to the next record because it's throwing an unhandled exception before that.

The last part of your code should look more like:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
catch (WebException ex) { }
finally
{
    if (response != null) response.Dispose();
}
```